# Basic Specular Shading

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I am playing around with a simple code that generates a shaded sphere. I don't yet fully understand the math but I am figuring it out as I play with the code. I was wondering how one might implement specular shading into this based on this code. Any suggestions?

```
for (y=0;y<screenHeight;y++)
for (x=0;x<screenWidth;x++)
if (sqr((x-xcenter)*(x-xcenter)+(y-ycenter)*(y-ycenter))<radius)
 {
 vx=(x-xcenter);
 vy=(y-xcenter);
 vz=sqr(radius*radius-vx*vx-vy*vy);
 vl=sqr(vx*vx+vy*vy+vz*vz);
 co_angle=(lx*vx+ly*vy+lz*vz)/(ll*vl);
 pixel=co_angle*255;
 }
```

I was looking at this thread and the second image is what I am after. But I also don't fully understand the math there either: [Trouble with Phong Shading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132774/trouble-with-phong-shading)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: lx,ly,lz are light location. ll is light length: ll=sqr(lx*lx+ly*ly+lz*lz);

Comment: just a silly suggestion since this is tagged C++ didn't you mean `sqrt` instead of all the `sqr` ? Also if you compare against `radius*radius` you can ignore the sqrt for more speed,... Also I would compute the `vx,vy` before `if` and use `if (vx*vx+vy*vy<radius*radius)`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my first comment. Here it is again: lx,ly,lz are light location. ll is light length: `ll=sqr(lx*lx+ly*ly+lz*lz);` Spektre, I agree with your comments but any suggestions about the specularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To add reflection first you need mirror light vector by surface normal**

- [image: reflections]
- **all these are unit vectors:**
- `l` - (yellow) to light source
- `n` - (aqua) surface normal
- `r` - (green) reflected light direction
- `e` - (orange) to eye/camera direction
- **points:**
- `p` - (red) - rendered pixel position
- `q` - (magenta) - reflection midpoint
- **axises:**
- brown - reflection midpoint
- yellow - to light
- gray - to eye/camera

**So how to do it?**

- `n,p,e,l` are knowns or can be easily computed
- if light is directional then `l` is constant for all pixels
- if light source is a point then `l=light_pos-p; l/=|l|;`
- `e=eye_pos-p; e/=|e|;`
- now you need to find point `q` I use dot product for this `q=p+(n*dot(l,n));`
- now the `r` vector is easy `r=(p+l)+2*(q-(p+l))-p=2*(q-p)-l;`
- hope I did not make a silly math mistake/typo somewhere but it should be clear how I obtain the equations

**now you have reflection vector `r`**

- so add shading by multiplying pixel color by `m=light_color*dot(r,e)+ambient_light;`
- to add specular spots you need add to m the maximal reflections which are present only near `r`
- so `ca=cos(ang)=dot(r,e);` you do not need `ang` directly cosine is fine
- now to limit the specular cone size do `ca=pow(ca,5.0)` can use any exponent
- this will lower the values below one so it is much  much less then raw cosine
- the bigger the exponent the smaller spot cone size so now:
- `m=(light_color*0.5*(ca+dot(r,e)))+ambient_light;`
- you can also add mixing coefficients to change the ratio between specular and normal reflection light strength
- now render pixel `p` with `color=surface_color*m;`

Hope I didn't forget something it is a while I coded something like this...

Comment: Hey guys - thanks for a very detailed question. Since I'm trying to understand the maths behind all this, and more importantly how to implement it in C, I'll ask some potentially dumb questions. Such as: how do you calculate a dot product? So how would one calculate `dot(l,n)`? Also, what does the bar on each side of a variable mean: `|l|`. And if anyone has suggestions on how this is applied with the original code, that might help get me started as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich95 LOL that is basic vector math ... the "bars" `|x|` means `abs(x)` for scalars and if `x` is vector then it means its size so `|x|=sqrt(x.x*x.x+x.y*x.y+x.z*x.z)`and `dot(a,b)=a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y+a.z*b.z` where `a,b` are vectors and the result is scalar (single value)  .. sometimes it is written like this: `(a.b)` and if both `a,b` are unit vectors (they have size=1) then the result is `cos(angle between a,b)` How to heck you get to 3D shading without basic vector math knowledge? btw the line `co_angle=` in your code is dot product ...